# How to shut down one database in a db2 instance?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I want to shut down one database in a db2 instance with multiple dbs. 
I don't want to deactivate the db as it will reconnect when I try to connect. It should be completely shut down so I get a connection error when trying to connect to the db.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a programming question so it can be viewed as off topic.

There are different techniques, each has advantages/disadvantages.

- You can [quiesce](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008635.html) the database and later unquiesce it.
- or you can revoke connect rights, and later grant them, but this depends on how well your role separation is done.
- or you force off existing applications and then connect `in exclusive mode` as the instance owner (provided that your applications NEVER connect with instance-owner credentials).

Answer (score 1):

One trick you could use is to temporarily recatalog the database you want to deactivate under a different name; this will prevent applications from connecting to it using the original name, regardless of the authority they use.

First, determine the database path by looking at its catalog entry:

```
db2 list db directory
```

The value of the "Local database directory" property is what you need.

Now you can recatalog the database:

```
db2 uncatalog db orig_db
db2 catalog db orig_db as foobar on <path>
```

where `<path>` is the local database directory determined previously.

Once you force all applications currently connected to the database in question you will be able to deactivate the database:

```
db2 list applications
db2 "force application (<app id 1>, <app id 2>,...)
db2 deactivate db foobar
```

Later on you can restore the catalog entry to its original value:

```
db2 uncatalog db foobar
db2 catalog db orig_db on <path>
```